# How to refer to existing documentation

Tags: flutter, dart, dartdoc

Here's an example of what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
/// This is a doc string for this method. 
method1(){}

@method1DocString
////method 2 doc string added to method1's here.
method2(){}
```

So method2's documentation would be:

> This is a doc string for this method.
> method 2 doc string added to method1's here.

I'm fairly certain I've seen this done before. Saves having to rewrite documentation where applicable. Also makes it easier to maintain accurate documentation.

What is the correct syntax for this in dart ?

Comment: you mean https://pub.dev/packages/dartdoc#macros ?

Comment: Ahhhh yes exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much. If you make it an answer I will accept it

Comment: your welcome to write a self answer then ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does exactly what I was looking for, thanks to @pskink:

```
/// {@template method1_documentation}
/// This is a doc string for this method. 
/// {@endtemplate}
method1(){}

/// {@macro method1_documentation}
/// method 2 doc string added to method1's here.
method2(){}
```

In the documentation: https://pub.dev/packages/dartdoc#macros